# Delete one character to the right in Webstorm

Tags: emacs, editor, phpstorm, webstorm

This key binding escapes me. It is the same as emacs `Ctrl+D` and I've tried Googling such things as "delete one character to the right," "forward delete," "delete next character", etc.

Here are the [bindings in phpstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/basic-editing.html) which I assume is pretty similar to Webstorm.

Any idea what this action would be called?

Note this is what `fn+delete` does on mac. If there were a way to reverse engineer this keybinding and see what function is actually called in Webstorm, that would work. [I asked how to reverse engineer bindings here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173148/reverse-key-bindings-in-webstorm).

Comment: Isn't this just Delete?

Comment: @Chris that deletes a character to the left.

Comment: @Chris also, I'm on a mac. Windows does have a "delete" key that deletes to the right. There's no such key on mac.

Comment: I thought you were asking for the name of the function, so you could look it up in your keybindings. If you bind the Delete function to Ctrl+D, or whatever you want, you should be off to the races.

Comment: @Chris I don't know how to find the right-delete function. I can only find left-delete.

Comment: Does Fn+Delete do what you want? I believe this is the Apple keyboard's equivalent of the non-Apple Delete key.

Comment: @Chris yes, it does. I've always used ctrl+d (which is actually supported by default on mac) since I'm used to it from my emacs days and it's way easier.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, then. The operation is called Delete, it's listed on the PhpStorm page you linked, and you've got a key binding that works.

Comment: @Chris the operation called Delete on the phpstorm link does not delete a character to the right. Per its description it deletes selected symbol/block, backspace deletes left, and I don't see anything that deletes right.

Comment: My mistake. Is there some way to inspect the Fn+Delete binding to see what it's calling, similar to `C-h k` in Emacs?

Comment: @Chris not sure, added to question though.

Comment: Posted related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173148/reverse-key-bindings-in-webstorm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is buried a bit but, under the WebStorm menu, Preferences..., Keymap (under IDE Settings).  Scroll to the bottom of the window until you get to Other.  Click the triangle to expand.  Scroll down until you get to Delete, double click it and assign it Control D.  WebStorm might warn you that the key stroke is already assigned and gives you the option to remove the other command.  That's it.  Made me happy to find it as well.

Comment: I switched Macs over the weekend and my ^D quit working so I looked through the settings and eventually Googled it and found your question here.  Fetched the old mac to figure out how I solved it last time.  I use ^D along with ^A and ^E a lot, so it had to be fixed.  Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: Works for phpStorm as well.

Comment: It looks like this is now listed under 'Edit' rather than 'Other' in Preferences / Keymap.

Answer (score 3):

On recent version of WebStorm (I have 2019.1), the way to do this is to add ^D (control-D) as a second keyboard shortcut to the existing Delete function (the one that is run by the delete key).  Somehow with this combination, WebStorm knows to delete the character to the left with the 'delete' key, but delete the character to the right with the '^D' key.  (I also removed the ^D keyboard mapping for my Run Debug function.)

Answer (score 0):

If you [enable emacs mode](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/441773) this will be enabled.

Settings > Keymaps > click dropdown > emacs.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid full emacs mode.

Answer (score 0):

Why not **record a keystroke macro** that shifts the caret one place to the right and then deletes a character. Or even one that simply does `Fn + Delete` if you're on a Mac.

- To record a macro it is `Edit > Macros > Start Macro Recording`.
- To assign a shortcut key combo to a macro use `File > Settings > Keymap
  > Macros`.

I appreciate this is not quite what you're asking, but is maybe a good workaround if there is no a way to get to the underlying key binding.

Comment: Show's up as EditorDelete, which I can't find in the menu anywhere. (Have the answer from another though.)