# Reverse key bindings in Webstorm

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, webstorm

I'm having [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095392/delete-one-character-to-the-right-in-webstorm) and one way to solve it would be by reverse engineering key bindings in Webstorm.

Specifically, if I type, say, `Ctrl+D`, I should be able to do a reverse look up to see what function it calls in the key bindings menu. Or find it nested away in a configuration file somewhere or something.

Looking in `/Users/Dan/Library/Application Support/WebStorm7/` the only relevant thing I see is `editorconfig-jetbrains`, but it only contains jars which I'm not sure what to do with.

I've heard this is what emacs' `C-h k` does.

Thus far I haven't found any equivalence, and the bindings only let you go function -> key, not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically, if I type, say, Ctrl+D, I should be able to do a reverse look up to see what function it calls in the key bindings menu

Settings/Keymap, 'Find action by shortcut' button - is it what you are looking for?